# Visual Studio 2015 c++ breakpoint will not be hit

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hi I have a c++ app in visual studio 2015. My .exe's pdb wont work and it cant hit breakpoints. when I open the modules window, the status says Symbol format not supported. my debug file flag is /ZI in the projects settings. I've tried deleting the object and bin folders. When I create a new project, it hits the breakpoint. Any ideas?

Comment: Does Build>Clean Solution and recompiling change anything?

Comment: nope it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: There are a lot of Visual C++ programmers that don't realize they are using the C++/CLI extension.  VS2015 is no longer compatible, you have to use Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

I had use managed compatibility mode and use native compatibility mode both checked. Unchecking use native compatibility mode fixed it.

Comment: where is the setting, I can't find it

Comment: i was debugging a c++ library through a c# app. I had to go to the c#'s project settings > Debug.